# How to import OSM relations to PostgreSQL databases?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I have created PostgreSQL databases using Osm2pgsql. I have all the lines and points data.

1. How can I import the relations stored in OSM file? for example turn restriction?
2. Is there an easy way to visualize it in QGIS? similar to JOSM symbols?

Answer (score 2):

The relation data is in table `planet_osm_rels`.

Osm2pgsql is able to process some kind of relations, like multipolygon, route and boundary. Those are useful for rendering.

Turn restrictions are not used for rendering, so you have to extract the data from the table yourself, and style it like JOSM does.

Comment: For me it did not create that table... is there a special parameter needed for it?